# Get selected form data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a scenario where a page have multiple forms and I am trying to get the form data which is being submitted.

HTML

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
<form>
<form name="form2">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
<form>
```

jQuery

```
$('[type="button"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).parent().attr('name'));
});
```

I always get form1 in console. I also tried `jQuery('form')` in console and it is also returning only the first form. I don't know what I am doing wrong or it is browser feature.

Comment: close the firs form tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `Form` has not been closed properly, If you close it properly as `</form>`, then your script itself is working fine.

Change below

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
<form>
<form name="form2">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
<form>
```

to

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
<form name="form2">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It was my mistake. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Close `form` properly using `</form>`. Use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of `parent()` like below.

```
$('[type="button"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).closest('form').attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: close `form` properly using `</form>`. @kpsingh

Answer (score 0):

i think your main issue here is that your form tags aren't closed.

full html example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Submit">
        </form>
    <form name="form2">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('[type="button"]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).parent().attr('name'));
            console.log($(this).parent().attr('name'));
        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```